# Circle puzzle involving 5 nodes

Tags: geometry, circles

A circle has points A, B, C, D, E positioned on the edge such that the straight line distance AB is 1922, BC is 1798, CD is 1798, DE is 2162 and EA is $x$. BE is the diameter of the circle.

[image: Picture of above information]

What is the value of $x$?

---

Am I right in thinking to solve this I make simultaneous equations for the radius and then solve *x* that way?

Comment: Hint2: you can compute diameter $BE$ by moving $D$ to a point $D'$ where $CD' = ED$ and $ED' = CD$ and apply Ptolemy to the quadrilateral $BCD'E$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exchanging the lengths $CD$ and $DE$ to get a trapezium $BCD'E$, the following two equations hold for the diameter $s$ and the trapezium diagonal $d$.

- Ptolemy's theorem: $1798^2+2162s=d^2$
- Thales's theorem (followed by Pythagoras's): $s^2=d^2+1798^2$

Thus $1798^2+2162s=s^2-1798^2$, or $s^2-2162s-2\cdot1798^2=0$. Solving gives the valid solution as $s=3844$, whence $x=\sqrt{3844^2-1922^2}=3329.00165\dots$

Comment: You call _s^2 = d^2 +1798^2_ Thale's theorem but isn't it Pythagoras' Theorem?

Comment: @BenFranks It is _both_ Thales and Pythagoras, but to use the latter we need the guarantee of the former.

Comment: Can you quickly tell me how I format super/subscript in this forum?

Comment: @BenFranks MathJax is used for that. To make superscripts, write (say) x^2 and enclose it within dollar signs: $x^2$.